# Precision, why do Matlab and Python numpy give so different outputs?

Tags: python, matlab, statistics, floating-point-precision

I know about basic data types and that float types (float,double) can not hold some numbers exactly.

In porting some code from Matlab to Python (Numpy) I however found some significant differences in calculations, and I think it's going back to precision.

Take the following code, z-normalizing a 500 dimensional vector with only first two elements having a non-zero value.

Matlab:

```
Z = repmat(0,500,1); Z(1)=3;Z(2)=1;
Za = (Z-repmat(mean(Z),500,1)) ./ repmat(std(Z),500,1);
Za(1)
>>> 21.1694
```

Python:

```
from numpy import zeros,mean,std
Z = zeros((500,))
Z[0] = 3
Z[1] = 1
Za = (Z - mean(Z)) / std(Z)
print Za[0]
>>> 21.1905669677
```

Besides that the formatting shows a bit more digits in Python, there is a huge difference (imho), more than 0.02

Both Python and Matlab are using a 64 bit data type (afaik). Python uses 'numpy.float64' and Matlab 'double'.

Why is the difference so huge? Which one is more correct?

Comment: Should perhaps fit on Computational Science SE if asked nowadays

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Maybe the difference comes from the `mean` and `std` calls. Compare those first.

There are several definitions for `std`, some use the sqaure root of

```
1 / n * sum((xi - mean(x)) ** 2)
```

others use

```
1 / (n - 1) * sum((xi - mean(x)) ** 2)
```

instead.

From a mathematical point: these formulas are estimators of the variance of a normal distributed random variable. The distribution has two parameters `sigma` and `mu`. If you know `mu` exactly the optimal estimator for `sigma ** 2` is

```
1 / n * sum((xi - mu) ** 2)
```

If you have to estimate `mu` from the data using `mu = mean(xi)`, the optimal estimator for `sigma**2` is

```
1 / (n - 1) * sum((xi- mean(x))**2)
```

Answer (score 14):

To answer your question, **no**, this is not a problem of precision. As [@rocksportrocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482205/precisison-why-do-matlab-and-python-numpy-give-so-different-outputs/7482413#7482413) points out, there are [two popular estimators for the standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Estimation). MATLAB's [`std`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/std.html) has both available but as a standard uses a different one from what you used in Python.

Try `std(Z,1)` instead of `std(Z)`:

```
Za = (Z-repmat(mean(Z),500,1)) ./ repmat(std(Z,2),500,1);Za(1)
sprintf('%1.10f', Za(1))
```

leads to

> Za(1) = 21.1905669677

in MATLAB. Read rockspotrocker's answer about which of the two results is more appropriate for what you want to do ;-).

Comment: Ah, I just see @rocksportrocker is giving you the Maths background about this :-).

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of `std` at [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), it has a parameter called `ddof`:

> **ddof** *: int, optional*
>   Means Delta Degrees of Freedom. The divisor used
>   in calculations is N - ddof, where N represents
>   the number of elements. By default ddof is zero.

In numpy, `ddof` is zero by default while in MATLAB is one. So, I think this may solve the problem:

```
std(Z,ddof=1)
```