# Python NumPy vs Octave/MATLAB precision

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, octave

This question is about precision of computation using NumPy vs. Octave/MATLAB (the MATLAB code below has only been tested with Octave, however). I am aware of a similar question on Stackoverflow, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482205/precision-why-do-matlab-and-python-numpy-give-so-different-outputs), but that seems somewhat far from what I'm asking below.

**Setup**

Everything is running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Python version 3.4.0.

NumPy version 1.8.1 compiled against OpenBLAS.

Octave version 3.8.1 compiled against OpenBLAS.

**Sample Code**

Sample Python code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as la

def build_laplacian(n):
  lap=np.zeros([n,n])
  for j in range(n-1):
    lap[j+1][j]=1
    lap[j][j+1]=1
  lap[n-1][n-2]=1
  lap[n-2][n-1]=1

  return lap

def evolve(s, lap):
  wave=la.expm(-1j*s*lap).dot([1]+[0]*(lap.shape[0]-1))
  for i in range(len(wave)):
    wave[i]=np.linalg.norm(wave[i])**2

  return wave
```

We now run the following.

```
np.min(evolve(2, build_laplacian(500)))
```

which gives something on the order of `e-34`.

We can produce similar code in Octave/MATLAB:

```
function lap=build_laplacian(n)
  lap=zeros(n,n);
  for i=1:(n-1)
    lap(i+1,i)=1;
    lap(i,i+1)=1;
  end

  lap(n,n-1)=1;
  lap(n-1,n)=1;
end

function result=evolve(s, lap)
  d=zeros(length(lap(:,1)),1); d(1)=1;
  result=expm(-1i*s*lap)*d;
  for i=1:length(result)
    result(i)=norm(result(i))^2;
  end
end
```

We then run

```
min(evolve(2, build_laplacian(500)))
```

and get `0`. In fact, `evolve(2, build_laplacian(500)))(60)` gives something around `e-100` or less (as expected).

**The Question**

Does anyone know what would be responsible for such a large discrepancy between NumPy and Octave (again, I haven't tested the code with MATLAB, but I'd expect to see similar results).

Of course, one can also compute the matrix exponential by first diagonalizing the matrix. I have done this and have gotten similar or worse results (with NumPy).

**EDITS**

My `scipy` version is `0.14.0`. I am aware that Octave/MATLAB use the Pade approximation scheme, and am familiar with this algorithm. I am not sure what `scipy` does, but we can try the following.

1. Diagonalize the matrix with `numpy`'s `eig` or `eigh` (in our case the latter works fine since the matrix is Hermitian). As a result we get two matrices: a diagonal matrix `D`, and the matrix `U`, with `D` consisting of eigenvalues of the original matrix on the diagonal, and `U` consists of the corresponding eigenvectors as columns; so that the original matrix is given by `U.T.dot(D).dot(U)`.
2. Exponentiate `D` (this is now easy since `D` is diagonal).
3. Now, if `M` is the original matrix and `d` is the original vector `d=[1]+[0]*n`, we get `scipy.linalg.expm(-1j*s*M).dot(d)=U.T.dot(numpy.exp(-1j*s*D).dot(U.dot(d))`.

Unfortunately, this produces the same result as before. Thus this probably has something to do either with the way `numpy.linalg.eig` and `numpy.linalg.eigh` work, or with the way `numpy` does arithmetic internally.

So the question is: how do we increase `numpy`'s precision? Indeed, as mentioned above, Octave seems to do a much finer job in this case.

Comment: You are using `expm` from `scipy`.  What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: `expm` is a tricky function.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm.html cites an article by  Moler about '19 dubious Ways`.  The Pade approximation depends strongly on the preconditioning strategy.  The Octave doc for `expm` also discusses this approximation issue.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I may be wrong, but I don't think it should matter much as `scipy` calls `numpy`, no? Anyway, my version is `0.14.0`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Yes, I am aware of this, and am also familiar with the Pade approximation algorithm. My point is that Octave and MATLAB produce very good results, whereas `scipy/numpy` is off by quite a few orders of magnitude. We can actually diagonalize the matrix first with `numpy`'s `eig` or `eigh`, and then take the exponential of the diagonal matrix. This produces the same result. I don't know which algorithm `scipy` uses, but it seems this either has to do with the way `numpy` diagonalizes matrices, or with the internal arithmetic workings. Question is, how can we increase `numpy`'s precision?

Comment: @William: `expm` is implemented in scipy.  The source code for the development version is in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py; the `expm` function there is just a thin wrapper of the real implementation in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py

Comment: Try an issue search on https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Thank you for enlightening me on this, I should have done further research!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as la
import scipy

print np.__version__
print scipy.__version__

def build_laplacian(n):
  lap=np.zeros([n,n])
  for j in range(n-1):
    lap[j+1][j]=1
    lap[j][j+1]=1
  lap[n-1][n-2]=1
  lap[n-2][n-1]=1
  return lap

def evolve(s, lap):
  wave=la.expm(-1j*s*lap).dot([1]+[0]*(lap.shape[0]-1))
  for i in range(len(wave)):
    wave[i]=la.norm(wave[i])**2
  return wave

r = evolve(2, build_laplacian(500))
print np.min(abs(r))
print r[59]
```

prints

```
1.8.1
0.14.0
0
(2.77560227344e-101+0j)
```

for me, with OpenBLAS 0.2.8-6ubuntu1.

So it appears your problem is not immediately reproduced. Your code examples above are not runnable as-is (typos).

As mentioned in [scipy.linalg.expm documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.expm.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.expm), the algorithm is from Al-Mohy and Higham (2009), which is different from the simpler scale-and-square-Pade in Octave.

As a consequence, the results also I get from Octave are slightly different, although the results are eps-close in matrix norms (1,2,inf). MATLAB uses the Pade approach from Higham (2005), which seems to give the same results as Scipy above.

Comment: This is nice. I will try to reproduce this. I have tried before on two machines (same software specs, different hardware), and was getting bad results (as in the original question). I will try again.

Comment: I get the same results - `0j and 2.77...e-101+0j)` with numpy 1.9.0, and scipy 0.13.0.  I edited the typos.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thank you! I will reinstall Numpy/Scipy from pip and try again. I am really at a loss as to what might be causing this. Will report back on the results soon.

Comment: @hpaulj,pv.: May I ask how you installed `numpy/scipy`?

Comment: OK, this beats me. After reinstalling two times, I was getting the same problem. I then uninstalled through pip, and manually removed any remaining traces of `numpy/scipy` from the machine. I reinstalled from `pip3`, and voila -- works like a charm. No idea was had gone wrong before. Thanks, pv. and hpaulj, for running my code. I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @William: one possible cause is having a left-over old Scipy version  lying somewhere that is statically linked to a buggy old version of OpenBLAS (there have been a number of bugs in OpenBLAS matrix multiplication which can affect expm results).